# Approximation of any norm by a sequence of maximum norms (in spaces of finite dimension)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

it is about the following proposition:

Let $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space with $m:=\dim(V)<\infty \Rightarrow$ For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ there are some $\alpha_j^{(i)}\geq0$ and linearly independent $v_j^{(i)}\in V$ ($j\leq m$) with $(\|x\|_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ bounded  and $\|x\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \|x\|_i$ for every $x\in V$, where $\|x\|_i:=\max_{1\leq j\leq m} \alpha_j^{i}*|\beta_j^{i}|$ for $x=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \beta_j^{i}*v_j^{i}$ and arbitrary $\alpha_j^{i}, j\leq m$, non-negative.

I understand, that the norms defined in the hint are maximum norm-type if we choose V=IR^n, alphas equal 1 and the standard base.

We now that norms are equivalent on spaces of finite dimension and all related statements about the topology, convergent sequences and the continuity of linear operators. Does anyone know this statement or have a hint about, how do I choose the Alphas and vectors?

This result is required to transfer an integral inequality from such norms to any norm.

Many thanks :)

Comment: I am missing something here. Doe the elements of the sequence of norms have some special property?

Comment: This definitely does work. I am sorry for this misunderstanding and imprecise formulation of the task. I edited the task. The larger context is the proof of the well-definition of the Bochner integral with Daniell integral methods *without* using measure theory, especially simple functions.